# Messed up a Package in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

So I ran this in the console:

```
teengamb$sex = 0
```

I was trying to just see the values from the list where `sex == 0`, not just checking which was true and false, but now I overwrote the values. I tried removing the package and reinstalling, but it kept the values that I overwrote. Can someone help me? (as you can tell, I am a complete beginner)

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you saying that `teengamb` is a built in dataset from loading some package.  If that is the case, you can call the `data(teengamb)` again.  For example. `data(iris); iris <- head(iris); nrow(iris)
#[1] 6;
 data(iris); nrow(iris)#[1] 150`

Comment: Sorry, `teengamb` is from the `faraway` package!

Comment: you want `subset(teengamb, sex == 0)` ?

Comment: So that's what originally what I wanted, but silly me I accidentally just set all the values equal to 0. Now I'm trying to figure out how to reinstall `faraway` so that it has the original values of `sex`

Comment: You are probably saving your session automatically and then reloading it at each new start of RStudio. Therefore, the "changed variable" is automatically reloaded every time. Follow @akrun suggestion and reload the dataset (and maybe disable automatic session saving, which I find to be only a source of problems.... Tools--> Global Options --> Restore .RData....)

Comment: As others have said. You saved a session with the corrupted value. But you didn't change the library on disk. You could set: `teengamb <- NULL`, then restart, load the library, and everything will be fine. (Lots of other recovery options exist  and I agree that not saving session would be wise, but we were all newbs once.)

Comment: Followed these steps, all good now. Thank you everyone!